# What are valid arguments for localtime function?

Tags: c

I have a code here which uses localtime function. But for some values of its input argument, the code crashes (null pointer returned). I want to know about the allowable range for its input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm g;
  struct tm *gp;
  __int64 tim;

  tim = 7476811632013133299LL; // I know it's a weird number but valid for time_t
  rawtime = tim / 1000LL;
  gp = localtime(&rawtime);
  printf("Pointer gp = %p\n", gp);

  g = *gp; // this crahses because gp = NULL

  return 0;
}
```

So what can be said about the allowable range of input to localtime function?

Comment: I don't actually believe that `7476811632013133299LL` is a valid value for the `time_t` type.  Compiling this with `gcc`  yields `warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]`.

Comment: Yes it can actually be 32 bit or 64 bit. In my implementation it is 64 bit. So it's implementation dependent. For example using "printf("%lld\n", rawtime);" prints the right value on my machine.

Comment: It works fine for me, and `sizeof(time_t)` is 8.  What is this value for you?

Comment: As you're using __int64, you might be on windows, in which case the ranges of legal ranges passed to localtime is documented(or can be  calculated) here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf12f0hc.aspx

Comment: @dbush It's 8 for me too.

Comment: @nos Thanks! That helps.

Comment: this statement `g = *gp;` is not valid  cannot reliably assign an array.  suggest: `memcpy( &g, gp, sizeof( struct tm ) );`

Comment: Please detail what is wrong with `g = *gp`.  Looks good to me.  It is not assigning an array.  It is assigning a structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [MSDN page for `localtime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf12f0hc.aspx):

> Return a pointer to the structure result, or NULL if the date passed
>   to the function is:
>
> - Before midnight, January 1, 1970.
> - After 03:14:07, January 19, 2038, UTC (using _time32 and time32_t).
> - After 23:59:59, December 31, 3000, UTC (using _time64 and __time64_t).

Comment: Experimentally found valid VS conversions continuing in the next day also to Thu Jan 01 07:59:59 3001 UTC.  This small extension does _not_ appear to be connected to my timezone.

Answer (score 5):

The allowable range is not specified by the C standard.

Quoting the [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) draft:

> The **`localtime`** function returns a pointer to the broken-down
>   time, or a null pointer if the specified time cannot be converted to
>   local time.

You should check whether the result is `NULL` before trying to dereference it.

Comment: Keith's initial answer (which I hope he restores) made the same point I was about to make: it's likely that `localtime` failed for you because the `tm_year` field of `struct tm` couldn't represent the year as a 32-bit int.  The `time_t` value 7476811632013133299 corresponds roughly to the year 236930730641, a 38-bit number.

Comment: @SteveSummit: I deleted that paragraph when I realized that the `time_t` value is not `tim` (`7476811632013133299LL`), but `rawtime` (`tim / 1000LL`, or `7476811632013133`).

Comment: Got it.  As it happens, I've been working with the ado/iana tzcode sources lately, and pretty much the only time `localtime` returns `NULL` is if `tm_year` overflows.  But from dbush's answer, it sounds like Windows is different.  (Year < 1970?  My goodness.)

Answer (score 3):

For fun, I asked my compiler to try a deduce the result:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool Valid_time_t(time_t t) {
  struct tm *gp;
  gp = gmtime(&t);
  return gp != NULL;
}

time_t MaxValid_time_t(void) {
  time_t mn, mx, dt;
  time(&mn);
  do {
    time(&mx);
  } while (mx == mn);
  dt = mx - mn;
  for (;;) {
    time_t mx2 = mx + dt;   // Technically a problem as int overflow is UB
    if (mx2 <= mx) break;
    mx = mx2;
    //printf("mx %jd\n", (intmax_t) mx);
    dt *= 2;
  }
  while (dt) {
    dt /= 2;
    time_t mx2 = mx + dt;   // Technically a problem as int overflow is UB
    if (mx2 > mx) mx = mx2;
    //printf("mx_ %jd\n", (intmax_t) mx);
  }

  time_t mid;
  while (mn < mx) {
    mid = mx / 2 + mn / 2 + (mx % 2 + mn % 2) / 2;
    if (Valid_time_t(mid)) {
      mn = mid + 1;
    } else mx = mid - 1;
    // printf("3 %jd %jd %jd\n", (intmax_t) mn, (intmax_t) mid, (intmax_t) mx);
  }

  printf("%jd\n", (intmax_t) mn);
  printf("%s\n", asctime(gmtime(&mn)));
  return mn;
}

int main(void) {
  return (int) MaxValid_time_t();
}
```

Output gcc cygwin

```
2147483647
Tue Jan 19 03:14:07 2038
```

Output MS VS 2010 with `gmtime()` in `Valid_time_t()`.  (Curiously 13 Hrs later when using `localtime()` in `Valid_time_t()`.  It appears the upper limit for `localtime()` differs from `gmtime()`.

```
32535291599
Thu Jan 01 20:59:59 3001
```

OP's output when using `localtime()` in `Valid_time_t()`.

```
32535244800
```

YMMV

Comment: Thanks! That's great :).

Comment: @anupamb What does your machine report?

Comment: I had to make some changes to get it running on Windows. But the output is 32535244800.

Comment: With windows, was able to run `gmtime()` and `localtime()` to `32535244799`, `"Thu Jan 01 07:59:59 3001 UTC"`.  Could also run  `gmtime()`  to `"32535291599"`, `"buf = "Thu Jan 01 20:59:59 3001 UTC"`.

"
"