# Invalid argument when converting float to datetime

Tags: python, datetime, time

I have to get a `datetime` from a float using Python. I am tryint to use the following code:

```
import time
print (time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(float(63650571169.50261))))
```

But when executing this code, I get an error:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

The `sys.float_info.max` displays `1.7976931348623157e+308`.

How do I convert this float number into a `datetime`?

Comment: The code works for me on Python 3.6.1 on OS X, producing `3987-01-03 10:12:49`

Comment: What OS do you use? Works for me on 3.4.5 on Linux, same answer as above.

Comment: If we can't reproduce this but you *can*, you probably will have to do a strace to find out what system call failed. See [IOError: \[Errno 22\] Invalid Argument with clock() being passed in](//stackoverflow.com/q/3239883)

Comment: @MartijnPieters initial test, I can _partially_ replicate in Python 2.7 on Windows, with `ValueError: (22, 'Invalid argument')`

Comment: @roganjosh: for the `time.gmtime()` part or the `time.strftime()` part?

Comment: @MartijnPieters `a = time.gmtime(float(63650571169.50261))` throws the same error.

Comment: @roganjosh: So it seems that the OP is on an OS where the system call to produce the time struct doesn't support values this far into the future then.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i'm using windows 7 64 bits and python version 3.5

Comment: @MartijnPieters To be specific, I'm also on Windows 7 64 bit and Python 2.7.9. The reporting of the error has presumably changed between Python versions then, with Windows 7 being the culprit.

Comment: I am on Windows 7 64 bit and Python 3.5.1, and I get the same error that OP does. Playing around with it, it looks like the highest value `gmtime` can accept is `32535291599`. I wonder if that number is significant somehow? It's not particularly round in hex or anything...

Comment: Note: only the integer portion of your floating point value is used (it can be rounded up or down, but the decimal portion is discarded). Since you are getting a 22 error, I can only assume that Windows 7 uses *32 bits* for the `time_t` type, meaning you can't use dates beyond 2038..

Comment: @Kevin: hrm, that's a value greater than what a 32-bit signed integer could store. Does Windows 7 have a Year 3K issue?

Comment: @roganjosh: are you using a 32-bit Python binary perhaps? What does `import sys; print(sys.maxint)` produce?

Comment: Oops, I misremembered. I'm actually on Window 10. But that just means if there's an OS limitation at play here, it has lingered for a couple versions.

Comment: @MartijnPieters `2147483647` so actually it probably is. This is what came with Enthought Canopy though, and will do 64-bit calculations just fine. Then again, Windows converts int to 32-bit signed integer when using `numpy` e.g. my confusion here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41705764/numpy-sum-giving-strange-results-on-large-arrays

Comment: According to [What are valid arguments for localtime function?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35048512/953482), the Windows function `localtime` has an upper limit of 23:59:59, December 31, 3000, UTC. If `gmtime` calls `localtime` (or some other time function with the same limitation), then that would explain why it doesn't work on very-far-future dates.

Comment: @Kevin deleted last comment as noticed UTC and I'm currently in UK daylight saving time so I thought I made a mistake, but actually yes, it wouldn't explain, I don't think, why your max int input (which is also the same as mine) gives me `3001-01-01 20:59:59`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your OS is using the [ISO 8601:2004 (clause 4.3.2.1 The Gregorian calendar)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) with the epoch at Year 0.  This can be converted by applying the correct zero offset as:

**Code:**

```
import datetime as dt

# define some constants
epoch = dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1)
gregorian_8601_to_unix_epoch = 62167305600

def gregorian_8601_to_datetime(gregorian_8601_seconds):

    # get number of seconds from epoch
    from_epoch = gregorian_8601_seconds - gregorian_8601_to_unix_epoch

    # convert to python datetime
    return epoch + dt.timedelta(seconds=from_epoch)
```

**Test Code:**

```
print(gregorian_8601_to_datetime(63650571169.50261))
```

**Results:**

```
2017-01-01 10:12:49.502609
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply,
In fact, the datenum is number of milliseconds and the datetime must be from 2010-11-04 to 2011-06-11. An example of datetime:2010-11-04 00:03:50.209589.

Comment: So, you think that `63650571169.50261` is a number of milliseconds from a base time, and it represents a date between 2010-11-04 to 2011-06-11? This is highly unlikely since it would mean the epoch date was sometime between `2008-10-28` and `2009-06-04`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Stephan, for simple examples its worked but then I wanted to use it as a function for bigger computations and I had the error bellow : OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

Comment: @Amy21, thanks for the feedback.  The best thing for you to do is ask a new question.  Be sure to include an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and if desired, provide a link to this answer.  You can put another comment here with a link to the new question if you want me to be sure and see it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
import datetime
print datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(63650571169.50261)
#3987-01-03 05:12:49.502609
```

Comment: It doesn't work, the same error persist. i'm using windows 7 64 bits and python version 3.5