# Errno 22 Invalid argument when converting unix

Tags: python

I am trying to convert unix time to human readable time in python and am either getting an error, or the date:1969-12-31 18:00:00.

When I run:

```
    datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp((1540254404.9600408)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

I am getting error:

```
[Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

I have also tried a few other functons like:

```
time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(int(1540254404.9600408)))
```

which returns: '1969-12-31 18:00:00', which is also not correct...

my unix value as noted above is: 1540254404.9600408

Comment: At least the timestamp is good, it gives me "Mon Oct 22 20:26:44 EDT 2018" using bash $(date -d @1540254404.9600408).

Comment: Both of them work fine for me in Python 3.6 on Mac OS High Sierra.

Comment: And Python 3.2 on Linux Debian.

Comment: Also works in 2.7.3 on Linux.

Comment: This might be relevant to your case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43099558/invalid-argument-when-converting-float-to-datetime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I just did, and it works fine!  Using Python 3.5.2, Pycharm, Mint18.  Same result with 2.7.12.

```
from datetime import *

print(datetime.fromtimestamp((1540254404.9600408)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

The printed result is: 2018-10-22 20:26:44.  Remove one of the "datetime" in your code.  No need to reference datetime twice.

Or if you do the import differently:

```
import datetime

print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp((1540254404.9600408)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

The same applies for your second line of code:

```
import time

print(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(int(1540254404.9600408))))
```

---

Another note, time.timestamp is a float, not an int.

Comment: If you just do `import datetime` then you have to write `datetime` twice. The two methods are equivalent. If he weren't naming the function properly he'd get a different error.